# IntelliJ IDEA Template Variables Collide with XML Properties

Tags: xml, templates, ant, intellij-idea

I find myself using a very similar Ant build script for all of my projects, so I decided to template the build.xml. However, the syntax for IntelliJ IDEA's custom template variables (that it asks for when you pick the template) is exactly the same as Ant's syntax for accessing properties.

```
${FULLY_QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME} <- custom template variable that I leave undefined
${basedir}                    <- provided by Ant
```

<sup>See [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html) and [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#built-in-props)</sup>

When I generate a file from the template, I anticipated that it would ask me for the value of `FULLY_QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME`, and it did, however, it also asked me for `basedir` and `DSTAMP`. Both basedir and DSTAMP should be set (basedir is set by default and DSTAMP is set by [TStamp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html)).

I thought it might be that these two are picked because they don't have a declaration like

```
<property name="foo" value="bar"/>
```

but I also use other built-in properties like `java.home`, which also don't have declarations, and I was not asked for those.

How can I get around this and convince IntelliJ to leave these properties alone, that Ant will provide the value for them?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I found was to mask these two particular values with slightly different names. For instance, I used the line

```
<property name="this.basedir" refid="basedir"/>
```

```
<dirname property="this.basedir" file="${ant.file}"/>
<!-- EDIT: for some reason, IntelliJ didn't like me refid'ing basedir.
     This works if ${ant.file} is in the project root. -->
```

to avoid typing the particular notation that causes the problem. I renamed DSTAMP by giving TStamp a prefix:

```
<tstamp prefix="this"/>
```

so now I call `${this.basedir}` and `${this.DSTAMP}` and IntelliJ is happy. I still don't know why it does this, and for these values in particular, but masking them does appear to be a valid solution.